# Evaluating Models that Return Percentage Present of Multiple Classes

Tags: modeling

If there is a model that returns a vector of the amount of different classes present in the data as percentages, what would be a good way to evaluate it (with charts and/or statistics)?

Say, for example, that a batch of pond water contains 30% Bacteria1 and 70% Bacteria2 (data is [0.3, 0.7]. Our model returns 35% Bacteria1 and 65% Bacteria2 (output is [0.35, 0.65]). How would we evaluate the accuracy of this model?

Am I right in thinking that we can't use things like confusion matrices or ROC/AUC curves because this isn't a classification problem? I'm not sure if there exist other metrics like these ones for this kind of problem though.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: I'm using Python

Comment: This isn't a question about programming ("charts and/or statistics"?).